# Webpack and babel: import issues

Tags: webpack, babeljs

**Issue**:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
import { merge } from 'webpack-merge';
```

I use the command below and get this error message. I've read multiple issues about that on github and did what they suggested, but I still get this error message. So, .babelrc and command are:

Command:

```
cross-env NODE_ENV=production webpack -p --config webpack/client.prod.config.js
```

.babelrc:

```
{
"presets": [
    ["@babel/preset-env", {
       "targets": {
          "node": "current",
          "browsers": ["last 2 versions"]
       }
    }],
    "@babel/preset-react"],
"plugins": [
    "react-loadable/babel",
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import",
    ["import-inspector", {
       "serverSideRequirePath": true
    }]
]
}
```

**Suggested solution**:
I inserted "@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import" in .babelrc file, but it did not help.

**Webpack config**: 
My webpack consists of two files: common and specific (either client or server, development or production). In that case I'll show only common.js and client.prod.config.js:

**1. common.js**
[image: interesting part]

**2. client.prod.config.js**
[image]

As it can be seen, the problem is inside of client.prod.config.js file as I use import { merge } from '...'

Comment: `@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import` will not help because it only works with dynamic imports, like `import("...")`. Do you mind sharing your webpack configuration? And also tell us a little bit more about the location of the file that throws the error. Usually this kind of stuff happens when you have ES6 code outside of your `src` folder, and it is not transpiled by babel unless you configure the loader to do so. Also, is your script part of a React app, or is it some kind of a CLI tool (judging by `webpack-merge` it looks like a CLI tool)?

Comment: @PavelDenisjuk updated! :) This script is a part of React app that uses SSR & Code splitting techniques using react-loadable, react-router and webpack 4
P.S: sorry about the screens, hope it won't make you feel obnoxious

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok so your main problem is that you are creating a `webpack` config but you are mixing in `ES modules` syntax. Since webpack is run from Node, no matter what version, ES modules will not work unless they are transpiled (using babel) to CommonJS (also, you cannot mix `module.exports` with `import`, it is either all ES5 or all ES modules).

The easiest solution for you is to convert your `import` statements to `require` and everything will work just like that :) Your `.babelrc` is of no use here, because it is only loaded once `webpack` kicks in and runs `babel-loader` on your source code.

```
const { merge } = require("webpack-merge");
const { join } = require("path");
// And so on...
```

Think of it like this: whenever you are configuring webpack - write everything in ES5.